# google script for sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

to send out emails. We have this working on two domains, but on one it's not working. Emails bounce back, and the bounce back screen looks the same, regardless of the recipient, a traffic light with a red light on

Message blocked
Your message to xyz@gmail.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.
LEARN MORE

I suspect it's blocked by google. It may have to do with our account status. Manually sent emails go out fine. But emails sent via script do not, they do appear in the sent box, but then bounce back almost instantly.

Does anybody know how to fix this? We have already allowed less secure apps in the g suite security settings but this did not remedy the problem. The g suite access is part of a squarespace deal, so not directly bought from google. The account is around 2 months old now.

Thank you.

```
function sendEmails2() { 
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT"; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Press'); 
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { 
    var row = data[i]; 
    var emailAddress = row[11]; 
    var have_email = row[12]; 
    var sendornot = row[16]; 
    var emailSent = row[17]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && have_email == 1 && sendornot == 1) { 
      var subject = "Story Pitch"; 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'name':'Lisai'}); 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: The way we can be the most helpful is for you to give us some code and tell us what the problem is.  We take the code and try to verify that we see the same problem and then we try to fix it.  If we don't have code nor access to your environment we can only guess at what the problem might be.  Once in while we might leave a message like this but most of the time we just move on to another question.

Comment: function sendEmails2() {
    var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Press');
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100)
        // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[11]; // test set for 
        var message = row[18]; //

Comment: var have_email = row[12];
        var sendornot = row[16];
        var emailSent = row[17]; 
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && have_email == 1 && sendornot == 1) { // Prevents sending duplicates
          var subject = "Story Pitch";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'name':'Lisai'});
            sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
            // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
       
    }
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I just made a few minor changes but I think it looks okay to me.

```
function sendEmails2() { 
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT"; 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Press'); 
  var startRow=2; 
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sh.getLastRow()-startrow + 1, sh.getLastColumn()); 
  var data=dataRange.getValues(); 
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i) { 
    var row=data[i]; 
    var emailAddress=row[11]; 
    var have_email=row[12]; 
    var sendornot=row[16]; 
    var emailSent=row[17]; 
    if (emailSent!=EMAIL_SENT && have_email==1 && sendornot==1) { 
      var subject= "Story Pitch"; 
      if(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()<1) SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Exceeded Daily Quota");
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'name':'Lisai'}); 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Good code. The exact same script runs fine on two other domains. It does run on this domain too, except the emails don't get out, it looks like google itself bounces them back in.

Comment: I wonder if it has  something to do with DailyQuota.  Try it with Gmail.